# SETNX result and distinguish between duplicity and failure

Tags: redis

if SETNX returns 0, can I suppose that key was not set due to duplicity (a.k.a may I be sure that key exists) OR there is posibility that operation failed due to some server error and thus the key does not exist in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I suppose that key was not set due to duplicity

Yes.

If `SETNX` returns `0` the key was not set because it already exists. In the event of a server error (for example: you are targeting a read-only replica in a replication topology) then `SETNX` returns an error instead.